# How to determine which input value was entered the most

Tags: java

I am having a hard time figuring how to determine which productType was inputted the most. For example, a person could input "water", "water", "coffee", and "milk". My expected output would be "Water was the most ordered product." This is my mainline logic. Can anyone help?

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final int MAX_GUESTS = 16;
      final int MAX_DRINKS = 48;
      double[] drinkCosts = new double[MAX_DRINKS];
      int count = 0;
      String productType = getProductType();
      while (!productType.equals("-1")) {
         if (count < MAX_GUESTS) {
            count++;
            String productVariation = getProductVariation(productType);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
               drinkCosts[count] = getDrinkCost(productVariation);
            }
         }
         else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Come back tomorrow.");
         }
         productType = getProductType();
      }
      double total = getTotal(drinkCosts);
      print(total);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a [`java.util.HashMap<>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). Use a `String` for the key type (the `productType`) and use `Integer` for the value type (the number of occurrences of that `productType`).

Each time you read in a `productType` (at the start of your `while` loop), check if the `productType` is already a key in the map. If so, increment the count that it maps to by one. If not, use the `HashMap.put(String key, Integer value)` method to add the `productType` to the map with a count of 1.

After your `while` loop, simply loop through the map to check which `productType` was entered the most (has the highest count):

```
int highestCount = -1;
String mostEnteredProductType = null;
for (Entry<String,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue() > highestCount) {
        highestCount = entry.getValue();
        mostEnteredProductType = entry.getKey();
    }
}

System.out.println(mostEnteredProductType + " was the most ordered product.");
```

EDIT:
To do this with only arrays, you will need to have two arrays, one for the `productType` and one for the number of occurrences of that `productType`. Since arrays have a fixed length, you will need to initialize them to the number of possible `productType`s (I think that is what `MAX_DRINKS` is?).

So, we create two arrays:

```
String[] productTypes = new String[MAX_DRINKS];
int[] counts = new int[MAX_DRINKS];
```

These arrays will essentially function as a map, with each `productType` in the `String` array mapping to the count at the same index in `counts` (e.g., `productTypes[5]` was entered `counts[5]` times).

Then, when you read in a `productType` in the `while` loop, loop through `productTypes`. If you find that type, increment the corresponding index of `counts` (e.g., if the `productType` is at `productTypes[5]`, increment `counts[5]`. If not (if you reach an element that is null in `productTypes` before finding the type that was entered), set that element to the given `productType`, and set the corresponding index of `counts` to 1.

Then, simply change the above code fragment I gave to this:

```
int highestCount = 0;
String mostEnteredProductType = null;
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_DRINKS; i++) {
    // Once we reach a null productType, we have reached the end of the
    // entered productTypes
    if (productTypes[i] == null) {
        break;
    } else if (counts[i] > highestCount) {
        highestCount = counts[i];
        mostEnteredProductType = productTypes[i];
    }
}

// Should probably check that mostEnteredProductType isn't null here.
System.out.println(mostEnteredProductType + " was the most ordered product.");
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this with only arrays?

Comment: @dan2693 please see the edit to my answer above. Hopefully that helps, but let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: @dan2693 I know that you already accepted my answer, but here's one more suggestion: it may be better to create a ProductTypeCount class with two fields: productType and count. Then, you only need one array of ProductTypeCounts, instead of two separate arrays for the productTypes and the counts.